# API Prestashop POST content_management_system

Tags: api, post, content-management-system, prestashop-1.7

i'm facing an issue with Prestashop 1.7 API

`Validation error: "La propriété CMS->link_rewrite n'est pas valide.`

`Validation error: "The property CMS->link_rewrite is not valid.`

I have tried to post **URL, URI, keyword, null** and nothing is accepted.

Someone know what to provide there ??? it s supposed to be controlled by isLinkRewrite

https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/webservice/resources/content_management_system/

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added for each language if have multiple languages and Use CDATA too for url rewrite and it’s have valid as per allowed data for rewrite url files too

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, unfortunately, i made a GET and try to POST it on a new CMS <link_rewrite> <language id="1"> <![CDATA[livraison2]]> </language> </link_rewrite> I have received a CDATA , 1 language and trying to send it back